# Do I need *********ApplicationContext classes if I want to develop using annotations only?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Its possible to create the context these ways:

- ApplicationContext context = new
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml"); loads context definition
  from an XML file located in the classpath, treating context
  definitions as classpath resources.
- ApplicationContext context = new
  FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml"); loads context
  definition from an XML file in the filesystem.
- XmlWebApplicationContext loads context definition from an XML file
  contained within a web application.

**But I dont wanna use xml configurtions in my projects at all. I like annotations.
So do I still need to select 1)...3) or just use annotations like**

- @Autowired                                         |     | @Component |
  generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component |    | @Repository|
  stereotype for persistence layer                    |    | @Service   |
  stereotype for service layer                        |    | @Controller|
  stereotype for presentation layer (spring-mvc) ?

---

**Or even I gonna use SpringBoot, there is @SpringBootApplication**

a is a convenience annotation that adds all of the following:

@Configuration tags the class as a source of bean definitions for the application context.
@EnableAutoConfiguration tells Spring Boot to start adding beans based on classpath settings, other beans, and various property settings. Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the classpath. This flags the application as a web application and activates key behaviors such as setting up a DispatcherServlet.

@ComponentScan tells Spring to look for other components, configurations, and services in the package, allowing it to find the controllers.

---

**So back to my question:
        Do I still need the *********ApplicationContext stuff in my projects or not?**

Comment: You don't need to use xml configuration. They didn't take the functionality out... I guess for backwards compatibility. If I were to to use it in a new project, I would suggest you to forget about xml. Here you can check sample projects: https://github.com/spring-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spring Boot you should create the context like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(TestApplication.class);
    app.run(args);
}
}
```

Method `run` here create the context for your application.